# MySQL Query: Get new customers in the month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have millions of records in a table with following columns:

```
id, item_id, customer_id, date
```

I want to find `customer_id` for a specific month which are inserted first time in the table in that month.

What is best and simple query for this.

Thanks

Comment: how do you mean by inserted first time??

Comment: @avisheks: means that customer_id first record in the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select customer_id , min(date) as min_date
from theTable
group by customer_id 
having min_date>=<the desired date>
```

Comment: This query works great, but I would like a MONTH column to also be included so I can see the number of new customers each month over say a 24 month period - is this posisble?

Answer (score 2):

try something like:

```
SELECT
date_format(date,"%M") month,group_concat(customer_id ORDER BY customer_id) customer_ids
FROM
<table_name>
GROUP BY month;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be:

```
select distinct(id) from customer
where month(date)='Your_month'
order by date
```